# Closing a Django Popuup

Tags: python, django

I have a popup that redirects to an admin page where a user can edit some contact details.  I want the popup to close when the save button is pressed

```
class ContactInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def Edit(self,emp):
           w=emp.personnel_id
           url='/admin/KUDZU/logmcontactinfodetails/'+str(w)
           z= format_html(u'<a href="{}" onclick="return showRelatedObjectLookupPopup(this);">Edit</a>', url)
    return (z)


model = LogContactinfo
fields = ('personnel','Edit','Phone','role','contact','note')
```

I've seen [Closing a django admin add related object popup window on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546386/closing-a-django-admin-add-related-object-popup-window-on-save) - where exactly do I need to override response_change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[response_change](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8f30556329b64005d63b66859a74752a0b261315/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1085) is a `ModelAdmin` method so you have to override it in your admin class (or Inline class in your case).